# How to connect Web Server to Glassfish Apps Server in different Windows Machine

Tags: apache, iis, webserver, glassfish-3, application-server

Recently has develop a Java Web Base and deploy into Glassfish 3.1.2 Apps Server. Due to security concerned, Company has decided to separate Webs and Apps Server into different machine and both is running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Has gone through some study, some solutions has applied accordingly but unfortunately, none of the solution is workable. All the solution that i got is talking about localhost setting but my situation is in different machine.

Been followed the step on the link that has shown but still no way to successful. Notice that the Web Farm Framework was not same version as showing in the web page. the version that i has downloaded from Web Platform Installer is 1.1 but stated 2.2 in the page. This has cause me not able to configure the Web Farm since after added new Server into Server Farm.
http://jstoup.wordpress.com/2012/04/25/how-to-integrate-glassfish-with-iis/

I had tried Microsoft IIS and Apache HTTPD as my Web Server but i still not able to make the Web Server communicate with my Apps Server.

Hence, would like seek for help from you all sincerely and glad that you all sharing your experience with me.

Much appreciate for help.

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some searching and study, finally i able to get a more detail guideline from web 

http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/03/virtual-host-apache-httpd-server-tomcat.html

Thanks to the author, i was successfully set up Apache HTTPD Web Server in front of Glassfish Server 3.1.2 in different machine.

The most important to configure the different machine pointer was at during configure the  session.

Hope that this answer can help those who facing the difficulties that i been faced before.

Thanks and Regards,